# Multiple inputs for driving a reset (RST) pin

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

I have an active high reset (RST) pin that is connected to a push-pull output. I am trying to connect another input to this RST pin, but this input is unable to drive the RST line high. Is this not possible because of the other output that is connected to the RST line? Can multiple push-pull outputs not drive a single pin?

Comment: You need an OR gate to do this.  in diode logic or CMOS

Comment: In some situations you may be able to construct the OR gate with diodes and a pulling resistor (especially when doing something like lashing together eval boards for a proof of concept) but if you are still designing the board single gates are available in compact packages.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Consensus is that I need to gate the signals going to the RST pin if I need multiple inputs to drive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, multiple push-pull outputs cannot drive the same pin.

If you want the "default" state of this pin to be low then you need to add a pulldown resistor to it, perhaps 10k\$\Omega\$ to ground. Then use drivers that can only drive high, such as PMOS/PNP transistors or tristate drivers that are configured to be in a high-impedance state when the output would otherwise be low.

Answer (score 0):

Run each push-pull output thru a schottkey diode. Then they can only drive high, and not low. 10K pulldown as noted above.